# How to get the original PDF file from Google Search (not the HTML version!)?

Tags: search, pdf

I am looking for the PDF file of this: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:-jKMIll8njoJ:isr.journal.informs.org/content/23/2/397.full.pdf+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de

The download on informs.org is restricted to registered members, but Google has obviously accessed the pdf file and created a HTML document out of it.

I would like to have the original PDF file instead of the HTML document. How is that possible?

edit: I don't want to save the HTML document as PDF. I want to access the original PDF (from Google's cache!?).

Answer (score -3):

Try to download [Cute PDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/)

You will be able to "print" the page and select "Cute PDF" as printer. It will save the content of the HTML as a PDF. It's not perfect but does the job for me usually.

Comment: That's not a good solution for me. I don't want to save the HTML document as PDF. I want the original PDF file, that Google certainly has stored somewhere. I know that, because some time ago (~2 months ago), it was possible to save the PDF directly from Google's cache. However, it seems, that Google has removed this feature. But maybe there is still a workaround for that.